# Error:The "android" command is no longer included in the SDK. Any references to it (e.g. by third-party plugins) should be removed

Tags: android, gradle

I get the above error when I updated Android Gradle plugin to version 2.3.0 and Gradle to version 3.3.

Here is my Gradle script 1:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'example.com' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:220bf7a88a7072df3ed16dc8466fb144f2817070'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'

    }
}
subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    version = '3.4.0'
    group = 'com.journeyapps'
    apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
    ext.androidBuildTools = '23.0.2'
    ext.androidTargetSdk = 23
    ext.zxingCore = 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42571270/997706

Comment: @Oskar, have you solved your problem yet? We also recently run into this problem, if you can post your updated version of your gradle file, I can help you take a look.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Remove this line from gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
```

This one work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this SDks:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip (form mac), https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip (for windows).

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552342/1214902

Answer (score 0):

**Try to remove this line**

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
```