# Error: The "android" command is no longer included in the SDK. Any references to it (e.g. by third-party plugins) should be removed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have cloned a project from github and getting the following error while building up the project: "The "android" command is no longer included in the SDK. Any references to it (e.g. by third-party plugins) should be removed." 
The gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

//    Scheme for version codes: ##@@$$$ , using:
//    ##   - the first two digits for the API Level,
//    @@   - the second and third digits for the minimum and maximum screen size
//           (1 - 4 indicating each of the four sizes) or to denote the texture formats
//    $$$  - the last three digits for the app version.

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 800410
        versionName "4.1"
    }

    sourceSets {

        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    // show deprecation warnings for all projects
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.7.1'

}

version = "4.1.0"
//version = '2.9.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = "be.shouldit"

ext.isReleaseVersion = !version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")

if (isReleaseVersion) {

    println 'Building RELEASE'
    ext.sonatypeRepo = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"

} else {

    println 'Building SNAPSHOT'
    ext.sonatypeRepo = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

}

ext.sonatypeUsername = hasProperty("sonatypeUsername") ? sonatypeUsername : ""
ext.sonatypePassword = hasProperty("sonatypePassword") ? sonatypePassword : ""

configurations {

    archives {

        extendsFrom configurations.default

    }

}

repositories {

    mavenCentral()

}

signing {
    required { isReleaseVersion && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task publishLocal(type: Upload) {

    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "file://$buildDir/repo")
    }

}

uploadArchives {

    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: project.ext.sonatypeRepo) {
            authentication(userName: project.ext.sonatypeUsername,
                    password: project.ext.sonatypePassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Android Proxy Library'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Proxy utility library for Android applications'
            url 'https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy'

            scm {
                url 'scm:git@github.com:shouldit/android-proxy.git'
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:shouldit/android-proxy.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:shouldit/android-proxy.git'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'lechuckcaptain'
                    name 'abc'
                    email 'abc@gmail.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Links that I have already tried:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720255/errorthe-android-command-is-no-longer-included-in-the-sdk-any-references-to?noredirect=1&lq=1
https://github.com/stetro/project-tango-poc/issues/9
```

etc.

I know that this question has already been asked but the solutions are not working for me as in the above gradle file there is not "sdk or apt" plugin used so please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Please specify what all methods you have already tried to solve the issue . Please attach the stack overflow questions link as well . also include the full gradle error log

Comment: Done and question is itself the proper error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved this issue, there was one more package in the project having build.gradle file, from there i removed plugin of sdk manager and error gone.